# Using the value from command line to form the char array and passing it to other function

Tags: c, arrays, parameter-passing

I am trying to read some data from command line, then passing it to a char array for the further processing.

```
#define former_array {"hello","world"}

void other_process(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *arr[] = former_array;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    other_process(argc, argv);
}
```

The original code is written in static way. I am trying to rewrite it by reading the data from command line. So I have change it into adding the word in main function:

```
std::vector<const char*> former_array = {};

void other_process(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *arr[] = former_array;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     former_array.push_back("hello");
     other_process(argc, argv);
}
```

But I have got the error.
error: initializer fails to determine size of 'former_array'
     const char *arr[] = former_array;

error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
     const char *arr[] = former_array;

I don't want to change the format of const char *arr[] = former_array; because I need arr for other process.
Any idea how to solve this?
Thank you.

Comment: ... and you are allowed to post formatted code here.

Comment: `std::vector<char const*>` -> `std::vector<const char*>` correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of the Standard Library and write something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> args { "Previous..."};

    args.insert(args.end(), argv, argv + argc);
    // you can start from   ^^^^ argv + 1 if you don't need the program name    
    args.emplace_back("final.");

    std::copy(args.begin(), args.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my original purpose is to read data from the command line, and then: const char *arr[] = {"Hello", "World"}; ,since I need arr for other process after this, I want to keep arr in its former format. I am not very sure how I can do it.

Comment: Well, if you really need `arr` you can still declare a `std::vector<const char *> args;` and then retrieve the data with `const char **arr = args.data(); int arr_size = args.size();`. See [here](https://ideone.com/IrKvdq).

Comment: Hello, thank you very much. I still have a problem here, is the *arr[] and **arr different? Since I can't use const char *arr[] = args.data();. But the program is not getting the correct answer due to I am passing the arr using the method you offered.

Comment: @aki Can you please also explain what *"the program is not getting the correct answer"* means?

Comment: Hi, thank you again. I think I find the problem. The link you have send is helping a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think I guessed what you want:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<const char*> former_array = {"aa", "bb"};

void other_process(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
  const char **arr = new const char*[former_array.size()];

  int arrcount = 0;
  for (auto & ch : former_array)
  {
    arr[arrcount++] = ch;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < arrcount; i++)
  {
    printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
  }    
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  former_array.push_back("hello");
  other_process(argc, argv);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works, but is there a way to keep this line: const char *arr[] = former_array;  because I want to use arr in other processing. After changing, arr is a different type and not match the original code.

Answer (score 0):

You have marked this as C++.

I am not sure I understand your question, it appears to suggest something about converting command line parameters to strings in an array.  IMHO, you should use std::strings but prefer std::vector,   please consider the following approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

class T504_t
{
public:

   T504_t() = default;
   ~T504_t() = default;

   int exec(int argc, char* argv[])
      {
         std::cout << "\nargc: " << argc << std::endl;

         std::vector<std::string> strVec;   // note 1

         for (int i = 0; i < argc; i += 1)
         {
            std::string s ( argv[i] ); // Note 2
            strVec.push_back(s);       // Note 3
         }

         std::cout << "\n  strVec.size() : " << strVec.size() << "\n  " << std::endl;
         for (auto sv : strVec)
            std::cout << "  " << sv;
         std::cout << "\n\n"<< std::endl;

         return(0);
      }

}; // class T504_t


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   int retVal = -1;
   {
      T504_t   t504;                  // ctor - create an instance
      retVal = t504.exec(argc, argv); // pass command line params
   }

   std::cout << "  <<< Did your C++ 'Hello World' have no class? "
             <<" Why did you bother? >>>"
             << std::endl;

   return(retVal);
}
```

Note 1: a vector is easy to declare, it is created with 0 elements

Note 2: ctor can use a char*, but assignment works too.

Note 3: a vector auto magically expands with push-back, no pre-allocation needed.

---

When run from the command line with the following parameters:

~$ ./dumy504  a  12  b  c  d  344

Note 4: all command line parameters are c-strings (i.e. null-terminate),

---

the code reports:

strVec.size() : 7

./dumy504  a  12  b  c  d  344

Note 5: c-strings are trivially converted to std::strings

---

Beauty is found in youth, and little else is expected.
class  is found in C++,   and little else is needed.